# Android APP multilanguage SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, locale, multilingual

I would fully translate my Android app. (this includes the SQLite is displayed on the phone language)

This is like now connect;

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quotes.db";
    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE_QUOTES = "quote";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    static Context myContext;

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        myContext = context;
    }
```

I had thought to remove the name string database and pass it the name database using the strings.xml file.

**super(context, context.getResources (). getString (R.string.DATABASE_NAME), null, DATABASE_VERSION);**

Also look for the query to pass on through strings.xml, but can not find clear documentation.

I would appreciate if I do not guide a little. Many Thanks.

Example the query:

```
// Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT name, COUNT(author_name ) AS count FROM author LEFT JOIN quote ON name = author_name WHERE name LIKE '%"
                + value + "%'  GROUP BY name ORDER BY  name ASC";
```

Comment: If you are switching which database is used based on language then you don't also need the query to use strings.xml, the result will already be pulling from a translated database, correct? Are you having trouble with the line in bold: super(context, context.getResources (). getString (R.string.DATABASE_NAME), null, DATABASE_VERSION);

Comment: Hi, Yes, These days I was trying to accomplish by placing the name of the database in strings.xml since the idea is to add more languages.

`public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
  File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(context.getResources (). getString (R.string.DATABASE_NAME));

  if (!dbFile.exists()) {
   try {
    CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
    System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
   }
  }

 }`

Comment: Also try: Cursor cursor = db
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT quote._id, quote.author_name," **+ Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.quer1) +** "quote.qte, quote.category_name,fav FROM quote,author WHERE author.name = quote.author_name AND "
                                + KEY_ID + "= " + id, null);
        try {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modifing the table  sqlite and code adding "+Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +":

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT quote._id, quote.author_name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +", quote.qte_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +
            ", quote.category_name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +",fav  FROM quote,author where author.name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()+
            " = quote.author_name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +" and quote.category_name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  +
            "!='Tips Romanticos' ORDER BY quote.author_name_"+ Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() +" "+limit;
```

The query result is:

> SELECT quote._id, quote.author_name_es, quote.qte_es,
>   quote.category_name_es,fav  FROM quote,author where author.name_es =
>   quote.author_name_es and quote.category_name_es!='Tips Romanticos'
>   ORDER BY quote.author_name_es  LIMIT 50